# How can we gain public Empathy?

Tags: social-psychology, sociology, empathy

I'm investigating how empathy operates within groups, focusing on identifying the specific factors that initiate and maintain collective empathy.
What key components are essential for triggering and upholding empathetic responses in a community context?

Comment: I'm sorry if my question assumes that you haven't. Can you share what you have found? Something you feel close to your need but it actually doesn't satisfy you

Comment: I’m asking here because I couldn’t find relevant information elsewhere.